# Ondrag event creates white space at the bottom of my HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code that detects if the cursor is being dragged left or right which upon doing so, cycles through an image sequence (similar to that of the Hyundai genesis website and its rotating car).

However, evertime the function is called, it creates white space at the bottom of the html page.
Any idea what might be causing this?

Here's the Javascript for loading the image sequence into the array:

```
var cache = [];
  function imgList(base,firstNum,lastNum) {
    var imageFunction;
      for(var i = firstNum;i <= lastNum; i++) {
        imageFunction = new Image();

    if(i <=9){ var EXT = '000'}
    else if(i <= 99){var EXT = '00'}
    else if(i <= 999){var EXT = '0'}
    else{var EXT = ''}

    imageFunction.src = base + "." + EXT + i + ".png";
    cache.push(imageFunction);
    console.log(cache.length);
   }

}
```

Here is the Javascript function that is called when the drag event occurs:

```
var prevX = -1;
var i = 0;
var drgleft = 0;
var drgright = 0;

function sequence(event){

if(prevX == -1){
  prevX = event.pageX;
  return false;
  }  
  //drag left
 if(prevX > event.pageX){
   console.log('dragged left');
   drgleft++;
   if(drgleft == 2){
   drgleft = 0;
   i--;
   if(i < 0){
    i = 30; //for optimization reasons, input the cache.length value   manually (this avoids unnecessary errors in the console and laggy framerate as a result).
  } 
  document.getElementById("TheBigOne").src = cache[i].src; //use      console.log(i); as a method of verifying that the code is executing correctly
   }
  }
 else if(prevX < event.pageX){
 console.log('dragged right');
 drgright++;
 if(drgright == 2){
 drgright = 0;
 i++;
 if(i > 30){ //for optimization reasons, input the cache.length value manually (this avoids unnecessary errors in the console and laggy framerate as a result).
        i=0;
    }
document.getElementById("TheBigOne").src = cache[i].src;
    }
 }
 else{}
 prevX = event.pageX
 }
```

Here is the html:

```
<div class="The_main_event" ondrag="sequence(event)" id="PlaneTime">

 <br/>

  <img src="file:///C:/Users/Foo/Desktop/Website/Web_aeroplane/Web%20Test.0031.png" id="TheBigOne" class="planepic">

 <br/>

</div>
```

Comment: Also maybe worth noting, The drag event doesn't work in mozilla firefox or IE (i.e. it doesn't cycle through the images).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, your question pertains to modifying images, and your code uses local images (which we can't see). Please update your code to use images that are available on the Internet, and show all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions :)

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the images are loaded or not, every time the function is called, it creates this white space at the bottom of the html page. Even if the function isn't triggered by an Ondrag event (i.e. an onclick event), the white space appears in increments (everytime the function is called, it gets a little bigger).

Answer (score 0):

If there is white space around an image, a small gap will appear underneath it as long as it is an inline element. There are a few ways to fix it, but the easiest is changing it to a block level element.

Try this:

```
.planepic {
  display: block;
}
```

Here's a demo

```css
div {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
img {
  max-width: 100px;
}
.block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W__wiaHUjwI/Vt3Grd8df0I/AAAAAAAAA78/7xqUNj8ujtY/s1600/image02.png"></div>

<div><img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W__wiaHUjwI/Vt3Grd8df0I/AAAAAAAAA78/7xqUNj8ujtY/s1600/image02.png" class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment Michael, the plane pic's display property is already set to block and the problem still remains.

Comment: @Mr_incompetent ah OK. Can you do us a favor and include all of the relevant code so I don't waste your time with stuff like this? And could it be that you have a `<br>` after your block level image? That will create blank space under the image.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I found the solution to the issue was something completely unrelated. There was a bit of javascript which was used to remove the issue of the image ghosting when the image was dragged:

```
document.getElementById("TheBigOne").addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {

var crt = this.cloneNode(true);
crt.style.backgroundColor = "";
crt.style.opacity = "0"; /* or visibility: hidden, or any of the above */
document.body.appendChild(crt);
event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(crt, 0, 0);
}, false);
```

Once I removed this code, the issue ceased to occur...
looking at this code now, I can understand why, I guess I shouldn't stay up so late and code rubbish like this.